# Nokogiri tag position before/after content

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I wanted to know if it's possible (and how of course) to get the position of a tag compare to the content of the parent tag.
For example:

```
Case 1: <a>Hello<br/></a>

Case 2: <a><br/>Hello</a>
```

Here i want to know if br is place before or after "br" tag

EDIT:
My real aim is actually to convert:

```
<a>Hello</a>
<a>World!<br/></a>
<a><br/>I</a>
<a>love</a>
<a>Rails.</a>
```

into

```
Hello World!
I love Rails.
```

But my current code is convert it like that:

```
Hello World!
I
love Rails
```

Because i'm looking for each "a" tag and if br exist i create a new line.

Comment: Why do you want an anchor containing nothing but a `<br/>`?

Comment: I try to explain my problem with simple things. If you want the details, I actualy want to convert my xml file into a txt file. And every time i have a br i want to create a new line exept if br is before my content. I'll edit my problem to be more clear about that.

Comment: Can you share your code? Because you can simply modify your "if br exist" logic to "if br exists as the last child" and then it would be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `children` when get `a`. Something like this:

```
str = '<doc><a>Hello</a>
<a>World!<br/></a>
<a><br/>I</a>
<a>love</a>
<a>Rails.</a></doc>'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(str)
out = ""
doc.css('doc a').each do |block|
  block.children.each do |node|
    if node.element?
      out += "<a></" + node.name + "></a>\n"
    else
      out += "<a>" + node.text + "</a>\n"
    end
  end
end
puts out
```

Output is:

```
<a>Hello</a>
<a>World!</a>
<a></br></a>
<a></br></a>
<a>I</a>
<a>love</a>
<a>Rails.</a>
```

You should cope with two br's in this case though...

Comment: Ty. It works but i'm but i don't get why :). Don't worry I think it's because I don't know what element? do yet. I'll look on Nokogiri doc.

Comment: It's any xml element of Node that can be Node itself and this helps to differ it from text inside node. Doc is here: http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html